# Horse race program simulation

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the second version of the original program I was trying to make. I have made a lot of changes since the first attempt. I am having having one or two problems at the end involving getting the position of the first horse.

```
import sys
from os import replace
from random import *
from time import sleep

# The horses
a = 'jack'
b = 'slow'
c = 'thunder'

# array for the horses racing
Horses = [a, b, c]
Position = []

# Race start point
countA = 0

# message afer race is done
msg = '\nRace Finished\nGetting results.'

# Length of the race
distance = 15

# starting amount
money = int( input( "Insert Money: " ) )
print( )

# The starting position of each horse
jack = 0
slow = 0
thunder = 0

# compare countA to distance:
def raceAlgorithm(countA, msg, distance,jack,slow,thunder):

    while countA != distance:
        dice = randint( 1, 6 )
        sleep( 1 )
        countA += 1

        if dice <= 2:
            jack += 1
            # print('\n'+str(countB))
            # print(a)

        elif dice <= 4:
            slow += 1
            # print('\n'+str(countC))
            # print(b)

        else:
            thunder += 1
            # print('\n'+str(countD))
            # print(c)

        if jack + slow + thunder == distance:
            print( msg )

            Position.append( jack )
            Position.append( slow )
            Position.append( thunder )
            Position.sort( reverse=True )


# Horse selection
def horse_selection():
    while True:

        print( '\n.....Select Horse....' )
        print( Horses )
        horse = input('\nSelect Horse:')

        if horse in Horses:
            print( '\n...........You have Chosen......' )
            print( '\n<<....>> ' + horse + ' <<....>>' )
            return horse
            break

# print your starting wallet
while True:

    if 0 < money < 51:

        print( 'You have €' + str( money ) + ' euros in your wallet.' )
        print( )
        break

    else:
        print( "This amount is not allowed\nThe limit is 50. Try Again!!" )
        print( )
        money = int( input( "Insert Money: " ) )
        sleep( 1 )
        print( )


def bet_amt(money):
    amt = int( input( '\nEnter the amount you want to bet: ' ) )

    if amt > money:
        print( 'Insufficient Funds' )
        sleep( 1 )
        bet_amt( money )
    elif amt < 0:
        print( 'This amount is not allowed' )
        sleep( 1 )
        bet_amt( money )
    else:
        money -= amt
        print( 'You have €' + str( money ) + " euros left." )


# If they want to pay
def myBet():
    # if choice is one of this
    Continue = ['Y', 'y']
    Cancel = ['N', 'n']

    while True:

        Bet = input( '\nDo you want to place a bet:\n Enter Y/n: ' )

        if Bet in Continue:
            bet_amt( money )
            break
        elif Bet in Cancel:
            print( '\nCome back again next time\nPlease take your voucher.' )
            exit( )
        else:
            print( '\nInvalid Choice. Try Again!!!!' )
            sleep( 1 )


def race_results():

    if jack in Position[0]:
        print(a)
    elif slow in Position[0]:
        print(b)
    else:
        print(c)

        while money > 0:
            bet_amt( money )
        else:
            exit( )


# myBet function
myBet( )

# picking your horse
horse_selection( )
print( )

# race countdown
for i in range( 10, 0, -1 ):
    print( i )
    sleep( 1 )

# Start of race
print( '\n..The race Has begun..' )

# race algorithm
raceAlgorithm( countA, msg, distance, jack, slow, thunder)
print( )

print( *Position, sep='\n' )

race_results( )
```

I am trying to print the name of the horse that's in first position rather than just the int. I get a cannot reiterate int error when i try to print the first position of the list.

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting? Can you edit the entire traceback into your question? It always helps to have all information instead of guessing which error you are actually getting.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please clarify your question. Provide any errors you are facing and mention the specific parts of the code that seems to have the error.

Comment: @lekan-swansons can you please copy paste the whole traceback? It will include more detailed information about the error/exception, and it will also indicate potential problematic line numbers in your source, and this will make debugging your program easier.

Comment: Too long. Wont let me copy and paste it in here.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the function to a variable and display the name of Horse wherever required.

```
# picking your horse
hs = horse_selection( )
print(hs)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [11]: type(jack)
Out[11]: int

In [12]: type (Position[0])
Out[12]: int
```

Your code is using `is in` for comparison which, I don't believe, is valid for comparing ints. You should use `==`

```py
def race_results():

    if jack == Position[0]:
        print(a)
    elif slow == Position[0]:
        print(b)
    else:
        print(c)

        while money > 0:
            bet_amt( money )
        else:
            exit( )
```

My results:

```
..The race Has begun..

Race Finished
Getting results.

7
5
3
thunder
```

Comment: This just prints thunder over and over. Either doesn't check position 0 or something else is wrong.

Comment: I didn't check the logic of your program, only the stated question that you were getting 'int is not itterable'. My answer solves that problem. In the two or three times I ran the code to verify, I noticed that Position[0] never actually evaluates to 0 however, the horses always do.

Comment: I thought once you fill a list with data, the first position is always P[0]. I have to add the total of the horses to the position but i don't want it to print the number rather the horse that the counter correlates to. So for the jack, if jack gets the highest and is put in the first position once the list is sorted. I want to get that value and print the name of the horse.

Comment: It is true that the first position is index 0. I think your issue is in how the counter is increased for the horse itself. I believe you have some variable scoping issues. It looks like you're trying to pass the horse names by reference as in C++. That won't work. The `jack` you are incrementing in your raceAlgorithm is not the same jack you passed in as an argument. Google around a bit about variable scoping in Python. I still think my answer is the correct answer. I'd appreciate you accepting it.

Comment: someone gave me a solution using a tuple.   ''' Position = [(a, jack), (b, slow), (c, thunder)] '''